# Mock an update method returning a void with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

In my test, I defined as data a `List<IUser>` with some record in.

I'd like setup a moq the methode `Update`, this method receive the user `id` and the `string` to update.

Then I get the the `IUser` and update the property `LastName`

I tried this :

```
namespace Tests.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UsersTest
    {
        public IUsers MockUsersRepo;
        readonly Mock<IUsers> _mockUserRepo = new Mock<IUsers>();
        private List<IUser> _users = new List<IUser>();

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
            _users = new List<IUser>
                {
                    new User { Id = 1, Firsname = "A", Lastname = "AA", IsValid = true },
                    new User { Id = 1, Firsname = "B", Lastname = "BB", IsValid = true }
                };

            Mock<IAction> mockUserRepository = new Mock<IAction>();
            _mockUserRepo.Setup(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(???);

            MockUsersRepo = _mockUserRepo.Object;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Update()
        {
            //Use the mock here
        }

    }
}
```

But I get this error : *cannot resolve Returns symbole*

Do you have an id ?

```
class User : IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firsname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Firsname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

interface IAction
{
    List<IUser> GetList(bool isActive);
    void Update(int id, string lastname)
}

class Action : IAction
{
    public IUser GetById(int id)
    {
        //....
    }
    public void Update(int id, string lastname)
    {
        var userToUpdate = GetById(id);
        userToUpdate.LastName = lastname;
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I'd like to be sure, the field Lastname has been updated correctly or not

Comment: @Kris-I that cannot be checked by your public interface at the moment. You may want to return the updated user or the last name from the method.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları ok I'll change the method to return the updated user, could you update your answer ?

Comment: @Kris-I Post your updated IUsers interface. I don't see it in your code. Does IAction extend it?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları my mistake it's IAction and not IUsers

Comment: @Kris-I What do you return from Update method? You can return a bool value that means update was successful.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları My favorite is return void but if no other choice bool or IUser

Answer (score 141):

If you just want to verify this method is called, you should use Verifiable() method.

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                   .Verifiable();
```

If you also want to do something with those parameters, use Callback() first.

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                   .Callback((int id, string lastName) => {
                       //do something
                       }).Verifiable();
```

**Update**

Here's how you should mock it if you return a bool value as result.

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                   .Returns(true);
```

Comment: There is now way to add an entry in List<IUser> and check if the value added exist in the list ? What can I do in 'do somehting' ?

Comment: @Kris-I I guess you keep List<IUser> inside the class you are mocking. If so you shouldn't concern yourself with the implementation of the mocked class. You should be testing the class that uses the repository.

Comment: List<IUser> is a list of data, available in my mocking class, it's just data for testing.

Comment: @Kris-I You are trying to mock the class you are testing. You should be mocking its dependencies. I think reading [this article](http://www.kaczanowscy.pl/tomek/2011-01/testing-basics-sut-and-docs) may help.

Comment: Hoooo that's strange, for me I don't try to mock the class I'm testing.

Comment: @Kris-I You want the mock object to manipulate the user list. If you write a mock that for doing this you still have no idea what your implementation does.

Comment: Thanks for your time. If you, you have to mock an update method, this method receive an int and a string. The update get an IUser with the id, and update on of the field. How do you do this ?  Don't pay attention at my code. Could you update your answer.

Comment: @Krist-l Post the class you want to test and I can give you some ideas.

Comment: Can I mail you will be easier ?

Comment: @Kris-I I think it would be better if we can solve your problem here so that other people can learn from it. If you are not comfortable with sharing some parts of your code, then replace them with comments or remove them completely.

Comment: We can do this by mail and when we found the solution I can replace my code and you update your answer

Comment: I'll send you early tomorrow, it's a little bit late. Thanks again

Comment: what if you just want it to return, i.e. NOT run the base method. 
so i don't need it to be Verifiable?

Comment: @f1wade What do you mean by the base method?

Comment: @f1wade You can create a mock with a strict behavior. If you don't have any setups, it will throw an exception when a method on the mock is called.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all, why is it so highly voted ?

Answer (score 24):

```
Mock<IUsers> _mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUsers>();
        _mockUserRepository.Setup(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                            .Callback((int id, string name) =>
                                {
                                    //Your callback method here
                                });
 //check to see how many times the method was called
 _mockUserRepository.Verify(mr => mr.Update(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Wish there were some details associated with this piece of code ! Would have helped.