# moq testing void method for Delete

Tags: c#, .net, moq

i need some help for testing a void method. can someone explan how void methods work with testing.

my services look like this:

```
public void DeleteUser(int userId)
 {
    var user = _dbcontext.Users.FirstOrDefault(usr => usr.Id == userId);
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            _dbcontext.Users.Remove(user);
        }

    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}




[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteUser()
    {
        mockContext = new Mock<UserService>();
        mockContext.SetUp(x => x.Users(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(userid)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the void method you want to test ?

Comment: Doing unit tests on actual database is not a good option, also if you are not using IoC there is no need for Moq here and it wont work if your class is not virtual. Besides that rethink what you really want to achieve with that test

Comment: See the related questions down the side. This may be a duplicate of one of those.

Comment: may be this can help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805812/mock-an-update-method-returning-a-void-with-moq

Answer (score 3):

Void methods can do two important things:

1. Edit state
2. Call some other methods

Since your method do not edit state directly what you want to test is that Remove and SaveChanges was called if the user is found and not call anything if not.

Mock has a special Verify method that you can use for both cases. Here is example how to verify that SaveChanges was called (which you can put inside if by the way):

```
mockContext
   .Verify(c => c.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

Or (the case where user does not exist):

```
mockContext
   .Verify(c => c.SaveChanges(), Times.Never());
```